# 500.19 Error from custom MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I have written a custom Membership Provider and Role Provider and locally these work great.  They are pulling all the correct data and writing correctly.

However, when i deploy this project to the web server; I receive a 500.19 error pointing to the web.config file.  I have narrowed the issue to the declaration of the membership provider

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ProjectConnectionString" connectionString="blahblahblah" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembership">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomMembership" type="CustomMembership.CustomMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ProjectConnectionString"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="60"
      applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Has anyone seen this issue before? or have an idea what could be causing it?

Technology
asp.net 4.0 with mvc3
locally - VS 2010
server  - Server 08

Comment: Do you see server response html with full error description?

Comment: yes, Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions. But i have given the web user rights to the folder just like all the other sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i see from using google, main reason for this is insufficient permissions, as error message says. Your file permissions do not allow the IIS_IUSRS (or, if your aplication pool is running on custom user, that user) user to access web.config (or probably any of the files).
One easy way to test this is to prevent remotely accessing website and add everyone full rights to that folder, just to see, that it is permission issue.